# Null vs empty field in database

Tags: sql-server-2005, hibernate

I have database in which data is imported from the other table. if data is empty there. so while importing to here it became null. When i query the columns like, name doesnot starts with 'a', it should return all records whose name doesn't start with 'a'. including NULL/empty column. its returning epty records but not null. But i need null feilds also. I useing hibernate and sqlserver 2005. how to achieve this.?please help.
Thanks

Comment: Can you add the query or how are you querying?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Null and Empty are different things.

When you say "Retrieve all the entries that do not start with `a`" it means that it will retrieve all the entries with **something** that is not `a`. `Null` is not something. `Null` is nothing. `Empty` is something.

You should modify your query to add `OR IS NULL`, to retrieve also the null fields.

Answer (score 0):

[From Wiki:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29)

> Null is a special marker used in Structured Query Language (SQL) to indicate that a data value does not exist in the database. Introduced by the creator of the relational database model...
>
> ...Since Null is not a member of any data domain, it is not considered a "value", but rather a marker (or placeholder) indicating the absence of value. Because of this, comparisons with Null can never result in either True or False, but always in a third logical result, Unknown.

Checkout this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/163434/82449).