# Is null bad within a relational database

Tags: sql, null, relational-database

Some people tell me null is evil within a relational database is this true or just subjective?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163434/are-nulls-in-a-relational-database-okay

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't go so far as to call them evil but on balance yes, the data management world would be / would have been better off without nulls. Nulls as we know them today are a feature of SQL, not of the relational model per se. The introduction of nulls into database systems and the errors that have resulted from them must have cost the industry many $millions over the years.

I can't put it any better than Chris Date in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kU-MXf2TsPE).

Comment: I just watched that one hour video (a Stack Exchange answer should not take an hour to get through). Chris Date explained his viewpoint very eloquently. I disagree with most of it. The last few minutes explain alternatives to `NULL`. One is to use "special values"™, e.g. numeric plus `???`. One is to split your data into different tables! E.g. `salaried_employees`, `unsalaried_employees`, `unknown_salary_employees`. Another is essentially an EAV model. He is trying to move responsibility for good design from the programmer to the database vendor.

Answer (score -1):

Null values in a relational database are bad. Some individuals (including senior level DBAs) will argue that some NULL values are fine for this that and the other, but this is like saying some water in a gas tank is OK. Yes, technically a car will still run, albeit poorly, with some water in the tank, but wouldn't you avoid it if you could? The more NULL values in a database the more SQL you will write for your reports.

If data is optional then the business model does not need it, so you're better off either leaving it out or enforcing that it must be captured.

For answers to this and similar questions, I cannot recommend [Database Design for Mere Mortals: second edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201752840) strongly enough. It was recommended to me by a software architect and I have yet to meet anyone who recommends anything else. There is also [a newer/third edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321884493).