# Dealing with a null attribute using java 8 streams and sorting using lambda expressions

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java-8

Let's consider a `Parent` class which contains only one `Integer` attribute. I created 6 objects of parent class and values of attribute are `100, 20, 300, 400, 500, null`.

Now I added all the objects to a list(Name of list is list). Then I want to get the objects whose attribute value is greater than `100`. I used Java 8 streams for this purpose.

```
Predicate<Entity> predicate = e -> e.getParentId() < 100;
result = list.stream().filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I also want to sort the list in descending order. I used the following code for this purpose.

```
Comparator<Entity> comp = (d1,d2) -> d2.getId().compareTo(d1.getId());
list.sort(comp);
```

In both cases I get a `NullPointerException`.

How to handle this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should we manage jdk8 stream for null values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081063/how-should-we-manage-jdk8-stream-for-null-values)

Comment: I'm unclear... is it `e` that is `null`, or `e.getParentId()`?  If `e.getParentId()` is declared as an `Integer` (the boxed type), it may be null.  But then when it's converted to an `int` to compare it to 100, the result will be a `NullPointerException` if it's `null`.

Answer (score 19):

Looks like you are looking for something like:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Entity::getParent, 
                               Comparator.nullsLast(Integer::compareTo)));
```

All the elements with parent null will be put at the end and the rest  will be sorted by their parent.

Comment: this solution worked for me. Because i don't want to filter null values.

Comment: Thanks for showing how to use Comparator.nullsLast.

Answer (score 18):

All of the answers here revolve around "throw out the bad elements, those that have a null `getParentId()`."  That may be the answer, if they are indeed bad.  But there's another alternative: `Comparators.nullsFirst` (or last.)  This allows you to compare things treating a null value as being less than (or greater than) all non-null values, so you don't have to throw the elements with a null parentId away.

```
Comparator<Entity> cmp = nullsLast(comparing(Entity::getParentId));
List<Entity> list = list.stream().sorted(cmp).collect(toList());
```

You can do a similar thing for filtering; define your predicate as:

```
Predicate<Entity> predicate = e -> e.getParentId() != null 
                                       && e.getParentId() < 100;
```

Comment: I guess you meant `Comparator.nullsFirst` because `Comparators` is from Guava

Answer (score 7):

Try pre-filtering for non-null `parentId` values only:

```
result = list.stream().filter(e -> e.getParentId() != null).filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[edit]
Just saw, that the attribute (`e.parentId`) seems the one being `null`. In that case, the second thing, the sorting, breaks. You are sorting the original list, not the filtered one. Try `result.sort(comp)`, then you should avoid the NPE.

Comment: This should work. You can also do `.filter(Objects::nonNull)`

Comment: The problem is object is not null, but the attribute is null,if my  contains 100 attributes, and I created a list of that objects , in which many attribute may have null value in some of the objects in the list, how should i handle this.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it all in one Stream pipeline :

```
List<Entity> result =  
    list.stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getParentId()!=null) // it's not clear if the null
                                            // is the Entity object itself
                                            // (in which case it should be e!=null)
                                            // or just the ParentId member
        .filter(predicate)
        .sorted(comp)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

BTW, according to the text of your question, the original predicate should be :

```
Predicate<Entity> predicate = e -> e.getParentId() > 100; // not < 100
```

Comment: Won't this filter `e.getParentId() == null` elements? He is talking about `e` being null.

Comment: @Codebender I may be misreading the question, but it seemed that OP created objects with parent IDs of `100,20,300,400,500,null`, so I assumed the null referred to ParentId. I might be wrong.

Comment: @Codebender that's not clear.  I think he's talking about the parentId being null, which is possible if it's an `Integer`.

Answer (score 2):

Harness the power of a **method reference** to make the code even more compact:

```
   List<Entity> result =
            list.stream()
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull) 
                    .filter(predicate)
                    .sorted(comp)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
Predicate<Entity> predicate = e -> e.getParentId() < 100;
Predicate<Entity> nonNull = e -> e != null;
result = list.stream().filter(nonNull)
                      .filter(predicate)
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Of course, you could **combine** the predicates into one, but I introduced a second one for better readability. Also, you're free to change the `nonNull` predicate to check either the whole entity, or just the `id` attribute (or even both). Just play a bit with it. :)