# Why does Stream.reduce(BinaryOperator) throw NullPointer when the result is null?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a stream of enum values that I want to reduce. If the stream is empty or contains different values, I want `null`. If it only contains (multiple instances of) a single value, I want that value.

```
[]              null
[A, B, A]       null
[A]             A
[A, A, A]       A
```

I tried to do it with a reduce:

```
return <lots of filtering, mapping, and other stream stuff>
       .reduce((enum1, enum2) -> enum1 == enum2 ? enum1 : null)
       .orElse(null);
```

Unfortunately, this does not work, because this reduce method throws a `NullPointerException` when the result is `null`. Does anyone know why that happens? Why is `null` not a valid result?

For now, I solved this like this:

```
MyEnum[] array = <lots of filtering, mapping, and other stream stuff>
                 .distinct()
                 .toArray(MyEnum[]::new);
return array.length == 1 ? array[0] : null;
```

While this works, I am not satisfied with this "detour". I liked the reduce because it seemed to be the right fit and put everything into one stream.

Can anyone think of an alternative to the reduce (that ideally is not too much code)?

Comment: This answer might give you some insight into why http://stackoverflow.com/a/17115490/1544715

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, all Stream methods returning an `Optional` don’t allow `null` values as it would be impossible to tell the `null` result and “no result” (empty stream) apart.

You can work-around this with a place-holder value, which unfortunately requires to suspend the type safety (as there is no type-compatible value outside the enum set):

```
return <lots of filtering, mapping, and other stream stuff>
    .reduce((enum1, enum2) -> enum1 == enum2? enum1: "")
    .map(r -> r==""? null: (MyEnum)r)
    .orElse(null);
```

`Optional.map` will return an empty optional if the mapping function returns `null`, so after that step, an empty stream and a `null` result can’t be distinguished anymore and `orElse(null)` will return `null` in both cases.

But maybe the array detour only feels to unsatisfying, because the array isn’t the best choice for the intermediate result? How about

```
EnumSet<MyEnum> set = <lots of filtering, mapping, and other stream stuff>
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> EnumSet.noneOf(MyEnum.class)));
return set.size()==1? set.iterator().next(): null;
```

The `EnumSet` is only a bitset, a single `long` value if the `enum` type has not more than 64 constants. That’s much cheaper than an array and since `Set`s are naturally distinct, there is no need for a `distinct()` operation on the stream, which would create a `HashSet` under the hood.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I do understand the reason you give, though the reduce I tried still looked very nice :D. I have tried collecting with `toSet()` before switching to the array (thought it was more concise and possible faster). I didn't know of the EnumSet, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Most stream higher-order functions don't allow `null` either as parameter or function return value. They are to prevent yet another [billion-dollar mistake](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare). Such response is documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-):

> Optional reduce(BinaryOperator accumulator)
>
> .....
>
> Throws:
>       NullPointerException - if the result of the reduction is null

Answer (score 0):

How about a really mathematical approach(hard to maintain I agree)?

```
Arrays.stream(array).map(e -> e.ordinal() + 1).reduce(Integer::sum)
            .map(i -> (double) i / array.length == array[0].ordinal() + 1 ? array[0] : null)
            .orElse(null)
```

Comment: There is no array to begin with and generating an array is already part of the work-around the OP want to get rid of.