# How to delete Null-elements from the Stream before applying collect?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null, java-stream, option-type

My stream function sometime returns `null`, when I do collect them How to delete that `null` return?

```
versions.stream().map(vs->{
        if(vs.matches("^matched string$")) {
                ...
                return new VersionNumber(tmp[0], tmp[1], tmp[2]));
        }
        return null;
    }).flatMap(Optional::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For this stream functions, if all matched is `false`, I mean if all the function inside the `map()` method, it will rise `NullPointException`.

How to make this stream not rise an exception and when all elements are `null` make it to return an empty list or `null`?

Comment: Can you please explain the logic: `map()` produces a stream of `VersionNumber` (not optionals, because you're returning `new VersionNumber()`), and it's being followed by `flatMap(Optional::stream)`, which implies that stream elements expected to be of type optional ?

Comment: If a function in the map returns `Optional<VersionNumber>` than you should not return if condition wasn't meat - return an **empty optional** instead.

Comment: If you eliminate `flatMap(Optional::stream)` that's expecting an Optional that you're not providing, then this question addresses how to filter nulls from a stream - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081063/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter afterward

```
versions.stream().map(vs->{
        if(vs.matches("^matched string$")) {
                ...
                return new VersionNumber(tmp[0], tmp[1], tmp[2]));
        }
        return null;
    }).filter(Objects::nonNull).flatMap(Optional::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But that is wiser to filter the sooner

```
versions.stream().filter(vs -> vs.matches("^matched string$"))
                 .map(vs->{
                           ...
                           return new VersionNumber(tmp[0], tmp[1], tmp[2]));
    }).flatMap(Optional::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: That `flatMap(Optional::stream)`  isn't going to work well on VersionNumbers and null.

Answer (score 2):

> if all matched is false, I mean if all the function in .map method, it will rise a `NullPointException`

Since you're getting a `NullPointerException` that means that your code compiles and running. Therefore, I assume that the "code" inside the `map()` operation isn't your actual code because we can't treat elements in the of `Stream<VersionNumber>` as optionals.

`flatMap(Optional::stream)` will not cause a compilation error only if preceding `map()` produces a result of type `Optional<VersionNumber>`.

Hence, my suggestion is simple: *never return* `null` *in place of optional*. It's completely wrong when an optional object might be `null`, it should either contain a value or be empty, but it should never be `null`.

And as *@Andy Thomas* has pointed out in the comment, there's **no** reason to utilize `Optional` if the code inside the `map()` really creates the object on the spot like `new VersionNumber(tmp[0], tmp[1], tmp[2]));`. In this case, wrapping the result of the `map()` with an `Optional` will be a misuse of optional. Return either `VersionNumber` instance or `null`. And then apply a filter:

```
    .map(vs -> {
            if (vs.matches("^matched string$")) {
            ...
            return new VersionNumber(tmp[0], tmp[1], tmp[2]);
        }
        return null;
    })
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You have to resort to the usage of optional **only** if inside the map you're actually **not** creating `VersionNumber` as you've shown, but, for instance, making an API call which return an `Optional<VersionNumber>` if some condition is meat.

```
    .map(vs -> {
        if (vs.matches("^matched string$")) {
            ...
            return getVersionNumber(tmp[0], tmp[1], tmp[2]); // method returing Optional<VersionNumber>
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    })
    .flatMap(Optional::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In such a case, there's no need to apply filtering. `Optional.stream()` when invoked on an empty optional produces an empty stream.

Comment: Alternatively, and more simply -- return null, but don't use `flatMap(Optional::stream)`.

Comment: @AndyThomas Good point. Improved the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As of java 16, there is also [`Stream.mapMulti`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)):

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of replacing each element of this stream with multiple elements, specifically **zero** or more elements.

(emphasis mine)

Using this, your example becomes:

```
versions.stream().mapMulti((vs, consumer)->{
        if(vs.matches("^matched string$")) {
                ...
                consumer.accept(new VersionNumber(tmp[0], tmp[1], tmp[2]));
        }    
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that the null values are not emitted downstream at all, so there is no need for filtering or intermediate streams for flat mapping.

---

Another example:

```
record A(String name, long count) {}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream.of(new A("apple", 1), new A("orange", 3), new A("banana", 0))
        .mapMulti((bucket, consumer) -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < bucket.count(); i++) {
                consumer.accept(bucket.name());
            }
        })
        .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);       
}
```

Prints:

```
apple
orange
orange
orange
```

3 oranges, but no banana