# Null values during Normalization

Tags: mysql, sql, normalization, database-normalization

Following is the table I am trying to normalize. But it contains NULL values (row 2, columns ROOM and TUTOR) . How can I proceed with normalization if there are null values in the table?
![Following is the table I am trying to normalize. But it contains NULL values. How can I proceed with normalization if there are null values in the table?][1]

```
COURSE
______________________________________________
ROOM | TIME | COURSENO | COURSENAME | TUTOR   |
_______________________________________________
112    9:00   1264       FRENCH 1     JL      |

NULL   8:00   1265       FRENCH 2     NULL    |

138    9:00   1266       FRENCH 3     PS      |

139    7:00   1562       SPANISH 1    KL      |

139    8:00   1563       SPANISH 2    KL      |

114    7:00   1564       SPANISH 3    KR      |

138    8:00   1264       FRENCH 1     PS      |

112    7:00   1264       FRENCH 1     JL      |
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having `Null` values.

Comment: use google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163434/are-nulls-in-a-relational-database-okay .

Comment: So for this particular table do I continue with normalization as any normal table with no null values ? or do I first need to split the table into another sparse table such that it does not have rows for items which have no value.