Key constraints in EF Core
Knowing that a PK can be a FK at the same time, I just want to make use of the data annotations attributes available in EF core to make this possible for the below entities (models) in C#:
public class ProjectDetailsModel
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("ProjectModel"), Unique, Required]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    
    [Unique, Required]
    public string Context { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
  
    public IEnumerable<MediaModel> Media { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectModel
{
    [Key, Unique, AutoIncrement, Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Unique, Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Unique, Required]
    public string Brief { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MediaModel"), Unique, Required]
    public int ProjectCoverId { get; set; }

    // navigation property
    public MediaModel Media { get; set; }
}

To confirm the above, when adding migrations, the FK constraint for ProjectDetailsModel to ProjectModel is not generated:
constraints: table =>
{
    table.PrimaryKey("PK_ProjectDetailsModel", x => x.ProjectId);
});


Your model is confusing. Details implies more than one, but your annotations would make this a one-to-one relationship. And the Details (Detail) table is so small - why break this into two tables when its really one entity? Its also not clear why the Details (Detail) has many medias but the project (same entity) has only a media.

You need ProjectModel as a navigation property, ForeignKey("ProjectModel") is not intended to work with type names.

@topsail That's true, ProjectModel and ProjectDetailsModel will be one to one. These two entities are separated because I will have two different pages meant for CRUD operations. ProjectModel will need only one media file, i.e., an image, and ProjectDetailsModel will contain more media files about ProjectModel.

Er, then it sounds like the data model is still wrong. ProjectModel should be the parent of MediaFileModel, and a project should have one or more media files, not a project has one details that has one or more media files. Don't let your UI / page design dictate your data modelling; that's why we have ViewModels as separated concerns from db entity models. I'd also be tempted to have one mediamodel designated as the main one by flagging one in the collection of many, not by having project relate to it separately

@flackoverstow Right, I even forgot about my ViewModels (DTOs). Now considering that ProjectDetailsModel and ProjectModel should be one, I am trying to understand how would I add data to this entity partially? I want to first add Title, Brief, Media file, occuring in a page, then in another page add Context, StartDate, EndDate and more MediaFiles. I guess I can let the latter properties be null, then add the required data? Would this be a good practice?

The question there is "does it make sense for the db data to be null?" - if the thing cannot work without all data present then it sounds like you have a two page wizard that collects all mandatory data into one or two viewmodels and then makes a single DB entity with all the filled in detail. If you want to have half completed drafts hanging around then you can consider stashing them elsewhere, or in this table but with nulls. Al in though, you need to disconnect your thinking about "what does the DB need" from "what does the UI need"

If you do use nulls, consider the impact on the rest of your code; it's a lot easier to write code if you're certain something cannot be null, as it relieves you of a lot of checking (so that your app doesn't encounter null reference errors) before acting. Hence, if I were being tasked to write some kind of "the user can slowly fill in this application form d buildthis thing" I would consider not having that "most of this object might be null" as the main entity I want to work with everywhere. I'd have a DraftProject they can slowly populate, but 99% of the codebase works with non null Project

@flackoverstow I agree with you overall. Another useful link regarding the usage of NULL is this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163434/are-nulls-in-a-relational-database-okay. Using the initial design would prevent breaking the 1NF, but it really depends from different points like the one you mentioned...
